# map value from one dataframe to another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data = {'x_axis': ['p1','p2','p2','p4','p4'],
                          'y_axis': [1,2,3,1,5],
                          'error_type_A': ['error 2', 'error 1', 'error 1', 'error 2', 'error 1'],
                          'error_type_B': ['error 3','error 4','','error 3','error 4']})
```

what I want is new dataframe like below:
[image]

How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.melt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html) with remove possible missing values and reshape by [`DataFrame.pivot_table`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot_table.html), then add missing columns and index values by [`DataFrame.reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) and last remove index and columns names by [`DataFrame.rename_axis`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename_axis.html):

```
df1 = df1.replace('', np.nan)
cols = [f'p{x}' for x in range(1,6)]
idx = range(1,6)
df1 = (df1.melt(['x_axis','y_axis'])
         .dropna()
         .pivot_table(index='y_axis', 
                      columns='x_axis', 
                      values='value', 
                      aggfunc=','.join, 
                      fill_value='')
         .reindex(columns=cols,index=idx, fill_value='')
         .rename_axis(index=None, columns=None))
print (df1)
                p1               p2 p3               p4 p5
1  error 2,error 3                      error 2,error 3   
2                   error 1,error 4                       
3                           error 1                       
4                                                         
5                                       error 1,error 4
```

Answer (score 6):

First set `y_axis` and `x_axis` as index using [`df.set_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html). Then use [`df.agg`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.agg.html), the unstack using [`df.unstack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html)

```
df1.set_index(['y_axis', 'x_axis']).agg(", ".join, axis=1).unstack(fill_value='')

x_axis                p1                p2                p4
y_axis                                                      
1       error 2, error 3                    error 2, error 3
2                         error 1, error 4                  
3                                  error 1                  
5                                           error 1, error 4
```

Comment: hi it works with the example above, but when I try with my real dataframe, an error comes: TypeError: sequence item 1: expected str instance, float found

but my real data is same as this example, where could be the problem?